# CefSharp ignores Preferences set with RequestContext (Spellcheck)

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I try to enable spell check for the CefSharp Chromium embedded browser (v3.3396.1786 installed with NuGet) and the CefSharp.WPF component (v67). I can get spell check to work with a single language but I'm not able to change the dictionary for spellchecking at runtime. I tried the examples shown and linked [on CefSharps github page](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#spellchecking) but without success.

My CefSharp browser always uses the the Locale to determine the language to use for spell checking no matter what I set with `RequestContext.SetPreference()`

This is my code which initializes Cef:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    var settings = new CefSettings
    {
        BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
            Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
            "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"),
        Locale = "de-DE",
        RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088,
    };

    // Set BrowserSubProcessPath based on app bitness at runtime

    // Make sure you set performDependencyCheck false
    Cef.Initialize
    (
        settings,
        performDependencyCheck: false,
        browserProcessHandler: null
    );
    CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
}
```

The actual browser is set up and created in another method:

```
private void create_web_browser()
{
    current_web_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden,
        BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings
        {
            FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            Javascript = CefState.Enabled,
            ImageLoading = CefState.Enabled,
            JavascriptAccessClipboard = CefState.Enabled,
            JavascriptCloseWindows = CefState.Enabled,
            JavascriptDomPaste = CefState.Enabled
        }           
    };

    current_helper = new ChromiumObjectForScriptingHelper(web_browser_ready_async, current_web_browser);
    if (ToolbarConfig != null)
    {
        current_helper.SetToolbarConfig(ToolbarConfig);
    }
    current_web_browser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", current_helper);
    var cur_dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var url = $"file://{cur_dir}/ckeditor/editor.html";
    current_web_browser.Address = url;
    current_web_browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext();
    current_web_browser.RequestContext.SetPreference("browser.enable_spellchecking", true, out _);
    current_web_browser.RequestContext.SetPreference("spellcheck.dictionaries", new List<string> { "en-US" }, out _);
    grid.Children.Add(current_web_browser);
}
```

An additional method is used to enable the user to change language later:

```
public void SetSpellcheck(Spellcheck language)
{
    if (language == Spellcheck.None) return;
    current_web_browser.RequestContext.SetPreference("spellcheck.dictionaries", new List<string> { get_locale_for_language(language) }, out _);
}
```

As you can see I try to set the spell checking settings but no matter what I set there, it has no effect. I could set `enable_spellcheck`to false and it still checks the spelling and the dictionaries I set are also ignored. Instead of what I put in dictionaries, the language previously set in `Locale` will be used. (I checked the out variable but there were no errors)
I also tried using the global RequestContext but with no success.

Apparently other people got it to work somehow so I'm feeling like I miss something important here, or doing something completely stupid.

Another thing is that, if I use `GetAllPreferences(true)`, to get a list of all the settings with defaults, I just get `null`.

Comment: You must call SetPreference on the CEF UI. Either set your preferences in http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContextHandler_OnRequestContextInitialized.htm or invoke on the CEF UI thread, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#threads https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/b31069633e06b22a5c24b7addded0a18f6e989bb/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs#L71

Comment: OMG, that was it. Thanks. Now I can see the preferences and can also see that I get an error `Trying to set a preference of type LIST to value of type NULL` when I try to set the dictionary although I can clearly see in the debugger that my list is not null or empty. weird. Searching the internet for the error just got me one unanswered forum post.

Comment: Upgrade to 71 or change the list type from string to object. This was fixed recently

Comment: @amaitland thanks now it's working. Fun thing is I tried object at some point but I just noticed my project didnt build on run anymore. 
Anyway, would you like to put this into an answer so I can accept it and give you reputation? Otherwise I write the answer myself if you don't mind.

Comment: Self answering is fine,  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @amaitlands's comments I now know that the issue was that I was setting the preferences in the wrong thread. I had the misconception that CefSharp was running in my applications UI-Thread, when it actually was running in its own.

The solution is to use `Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew()` to run the code inside of the CefSharp UI-Thread

```
Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
{
    current_web_browser.RequestContext.SetPreference("browser.enable_spellchecking", true, out _);
    current_web_browser.RequestContext.SetPreference("spellcheck.dictionaries", new List<object> { "en-US" }, out _);
});
```

I also had to change the type of the `List<>` to `object` since I'm using an older version of CefSharp.WPF otherwise I'd get a `Trying to set a preference of type LIST to value of type NULL` error.

Comment: For reference in version 71 you can use List<string>